# tcp 10.10.2.2:443: i/o timeout Cloud Build accessing private GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build, gke-networking, google-cloud-deploy

I'm trying to get Cloud Build to access my private GKE by following the instructions described at https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools

From what I can see I've configured things as described, but when I try to deploy anything or run the test described in the link above, I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.10.2.2:443: i/o timeout
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can troubleshoot this? My VPN tunnels are all established and my GKE cluster is allowing 192.168.0.0/20 in its authorized networks.

Here are some additional details on my setup for reference:

```
# gcloud compute vpn-tunnels list
NAME            REGION    GATEWAY   PEER_ADDRESS
ha-vpn-tunnel1  us-east1  ha-vpn-1  35.242.12.184
ha-vpn-tunnel2  us-east1  ha-vpn-1  35.220.15.95
ha-vpn-tunnel3  us-east1  ha-vpn-2  35.242.6.151
ha-vpn-tunnel4  us-east1  ha-vpn-2  35.220.14.211

# gcloud compute vpn-gateways list
NAME      INTERFACE0     INTERFACE1     NETWORK                   REGION
ha-vpn-1  35.242.6.151   35.220.14.211  demo-vpc                  us-east1
ha-vpn-2  35.242.12.184  35.220.15.95   private-pool-peering-vpc  us-east1

# gcloud compute routers list
NAME            REGION    NETWORK
ha-vpn-router1  us-east1  demo-vpc
ha-vpn-router2  us-east1  private-pool-peering-vpc
my-router       us-east1  demo-vpc

# gcloud compute routers describe ha-vpn-router1 --region us-east1
bgp:
  advertiseMode: DEFAULT
  asn: 64515
  keepaliveInterval: 20
bgpPeers:
- advertiseMode: CUSTOM
  advertisedIpRanges:
  - description: ''
    range: 192.168.0.0/20
  advertisedRoutePriority: 100
  bfd:
    minReceiveInterval: 1000
    minTransmitInterval: 1000
    multiplier: 5
    sessionInitializationMode: DISABLED
  enable: 'TRUE'
  enableIpv6: false
  interfaceName: router1-interface2
  ipAddress: 169.254.1.2
  name: router1-peer2
  peerAsn: 64516
  peerIpAddress: 169.254.1.1
- advertiseMode: CUSTOM
  advertisedIpRanges:
  - description: ''
    range: 192.168.0.0/20
  advertisedRoutePriority: 100
  bfd:
    minReceiveInterval: 1000
    minTransmitInterval: 1000
    multiplier: 5
    sessionInitializationMode: DISABLED
  enable: 'TRUE'
  enableIpv6: false
  interfaceName: router1-interface1
  ipAddress: 169.254.0.1
  name: router1-peer1
  peerAsn: 64516
  peerIpAddress: 169.254.0.2
creationTimestamp: '2023-01-03T16:55:55.711-08:00'
id: '2186172510416498804'
interfaces:
- ipRange: 169.254.1.2/30
  linkedVpnTunnel: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/vpnTunnels/ha-vpn-tunnel2
  name: router1-interface2
- ipRange: 169.254.0.1/30
  linkedVpnTunnel: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/vpnTunnels/ha-vpn-tunnel1
  name: router1-interface1
kind: compute#router
name: ha-vpn-router1
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/global/networks/demo-vpc
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/routers/ha-vpn-router1

# gcloud compute routers describe ha-vpn-router2 --region us-east1
bgp:
  advertiseMode: DEFAULT
  asn: 64516
  keepaliveInterval: 20
bgpPeers:
- advertiseMode: CUSTOM
  advertisedIpRanges:
  - description: ''
    range: 10.10.2.0/28
  advertisedRoutePriority: 100
  bfd:
    minReceiveInterval: 1000
    minTransmitInterval: 1000
    multiplier: 5
    sessionInitializationMode: DISABLED
  enable: 'TRUE'
  enableIpv6: false
  interfaceName: router2-interface1
  ipAddress: 169.254.0.2
  name: router2-peer1
  peerAsn: 64515
  peerIpAddress: 169.254.0.1
- advertiseMode: CUSTOM
  advertisedIpRanges:
  - description: ''
    range: 10.10.2.0/28
  advertisedRoutePriority: 100
  bfd:
    minReceiveInterval: 1000
    minTransmitInterval: 1000
    multiplier: 5
    sessionInitializationMode: DISABLED
  enable: 'TRUE'
  enableIpv6: false
  interfaceName: router2-interface2
  ipAddress: 169.254.1.1
  name: router2-peer2
  peerAsn: 64515
  peerIpAddress: 169.254.1.2
creationTimestamp: '2023-01-03T16:56:06.404-08:00'
id: '6144519957886103625'
interfaces:
- ipRange: 169.254.0.2/30
  linkedVpnTunnel: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/vpnTunnels/ha-vpn-tunnel3
  name: router2-interface1
- ipRange: 169.254.1.1/30
  linkedVpnTunnel: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/vpnTunnels/ha-vpn-tunnel4
  name: router2-interface2
kind: compute#router
name: ha-vpn-router2
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/global/networks/private-pool-peering-vpc
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fakeproject/regions/us-east1/routers/ha-vpn-router2
```

Thanks!

Update 2022-01-04:

I have a cloudbuild.yaml file matching the example from the link above which I've just updated to run a kubectl get config instead of kubectl get nodes. Here is the result of that command:

```
Running: kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://10.10.2.2
  name: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
    user: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
  name: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
current-context: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_fake-project_us-east1_demo-gke
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: xxx
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2023-01-05T03:17:33Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
PUSH
DONE
```

Here's the output showing my authorized networks as well:

```
gcloud container clusters describe demo-gke \
>       --format="value(masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig)"\
>       --region=us-east1
cidrBlocks=[{'cidrBlock': '10.0.0.0/8', 'displayName': 'internal_10'}, {'cidrBlock': '192.168.0.0/16', 'displayName': 'internal_192'}, {'cidrBlock': '172.16.0.0/12', 'displayName': 'internal_172'}];enabled=True
```

Comment: kubectl config view will just display the content of your .kube/config and gcloud container clusters describe talks to the GKE API to display info about the cluster. Neither talk to the controle plane of your cluster.

A timeout could mean a missconfigured firewall somewhere. I'm too familiar with that particular solution but can you look at your firewall rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was I had a typo in one of my BGP advertised routes. Once I fixed that up everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [IP_ADDRESS]: connect:
> connection timed out.

This can occur when kubectl is unable to talk to the cluster control plane.

To resolve this issue, verify the context where the cluster is set:

1. Go to `$HOME/.kube/config` or run the command `kubectl config view` to verify the config file contains the cluster context and the external IP address of the control plane.
2. Set the cluster credentials:

> ```
>  gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME \
>         --region=COMPUTE_REGION
> ```

Replace the following:

`CLUSTER_NAME:` the name of your cluster.

`COMPUTE_REGION:` the Compute Engine region for your cluster. For zonal clusters, use --zone=COMPUTE_ZONE.

Follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#troubleshooting) which has muliple methods for troubleshooting that can't reach the control plane of a private cluster, try them and let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that this is all supposed to be running from my Cloud Build worker pool so not something I can login to to manually run these commands to my knowledge. I've added an update to my original question above showing the output of the `kubectl config view` command run from my build though. 

By setting the following in my clouddeploy.yaml file, my understand is this should go and grab the required creds on its own:

`gke:
  cluster: projects/fakeproject/locations/us-east1/clusters/demo-gke`

Sorry, I doubt this provides a lot of extra assistance though.